# Mudar a orientação de uma tabela de uma tabela usando apenas o CSS e sem alterar o código HTML

Tags: html, css, tabela-html

Preciso alterar a orientação de uma tabela para que a orientação dela esteja com com as colunas em linha e as linhas em coluna. Não posso alterar o documento HTML. Desejo que minha tabela fique como na imagem abaixo.[image: Como desejo que minha tabela fique]

Este é o código fonte da minha página. Lembrando que não posso alterar o meu HTML, apenas o CSS. Apliquei o estilo que desejo mas preciso mudar a orientação da tabela

```css
body{
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 10px;
}
th, td {
    padding: 0.25em;
    text-align: center;
}
thead {
    background-color: lightseagreen;
}
table thead th:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: darkgreen;
}
tbody {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Layout 2</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout2.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Data</th>
                <th>Código</th>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Preço</th>
                <th>Quantidade</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>2022-01-24</td>
                <td>63384</td>
                <td>Tênis</td>
                <td>R$ 83,85</td>
                <td>83</td>
                <td>R$ 6.996,54</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2022-03-12</td>
                <td>109707</td>
                <td>Caderno</td>
                <td>R$ 96,43</td>
                <td>49</td>
                <td>R$ 4.700,30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2022-04-23</td>
                <td>2850</td>
                <td>Pendrive</td>
                <td>R$ 14,79</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>R$ 741,65</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2022-05-17</td>
                <td>145406</td>
                <td>Mouse</td>
                <td>R$ 48,54</td>
                <td>76</td>
                <td>R$ 3.709,31</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2022-03-08</td>
                <td>193392</td>
                <td>Teclado</td>
                <td>R$ 79,94</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>R$ 5.092,43</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2022-05-23</td>
                <td>141667</td>
                <td>Câmera</td>
                <td>R$ 64,70</td>
                <td>52</td>
                <td>R$ 3.364,53</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2022-02-16</td>
                <td>71475</td>
                <td>Porta retrato</td>
                <td>R$ 66,57</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>R$ 4.266,20</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2022-01-29</td>
                <td>141086</td>
                <td>Talheres</td>
                <td>R$ 75,10</td>
                <td>82</td>
                <td>R$ 6.132,61</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2022-01-08</td>
                <td>54067</td>
                <td>Conjunto de pratos</td>
                <td>R$ 58,85</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>R$ 3.724,07</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2022-04-17</td>
                <td>155434</td>
                <td>Fone de ouvido</td>
                <td>R$ 47,63</td>
                <td>79</td>
                <td>R$ 3.760,59</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2022-03-10</td>
                <td>27264</td>
                <td>Microfone</td>
                <td>R$ 32,39</td>
                <td>98</td>
                <td>R$ 3.168,70</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2022-05-23</td>
                <td>91936</td>
                <td>Adaptador</td>
                <td>R$ 91,84</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>R$ 2.644,86</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2022-03-29</td>
                <td>56326</td>
                <td>Cabos</td>
                <td>R$ 2,67</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>R$ 27,62</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2022-05-02</td>
                <td>33430</td>
                <td>Suporte</td>
                <td>R$ 1,15</td>
                <td>76</td>
                <td>R$ 87,92</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2022-01-18</td>
                <td>128696</td>
                <td>Apoio de pé</td>
                <td>R$ 79,69</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>R$ 1.780,00</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Queira seguir [as instruções dadas na 1a vez que fez essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/555082/#comment987683_555082). Ao editar aquela postagem, ela entrará numa revisão automática pela comunidade.